# Database Modeling: avoid using primary keys based on multiple columns merging them into one column that acts as a Primary Key

Tags: data-modeling

Have more than 1 column in Primary Key (PK) makes composing queries more difficult and create Foreign Key cumbersome

So when I have 1 table with Pk composed with 2 columns : Col1 and Col2 
I merge these into  PK =Col1 & "-" Col2 ( using "-" as separator) and then I add a table constraints to check that the constraint is respected.

Can this behavior considered a good practise?

Thank you

Comment: I don't quite understand the question but anything that involves concatenating several disjunct data items in a string and then performing various operations on it sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: A table **cannot** ever have more than one primary key - by definition, there's also only ***ONE*** primary key (which *can* be made up from multiple columns - but it's **one key**)

Comment: @marc_s You can however have as many unique and non-null columns as you want, but that's a different thing.

Comment: Thank you marc_s for the observation. What I want to do is merge the columns forming the Primary Key into 1 column than acts as Primary Key

Comment: You cannot have more than one primary key, you can however have a primary key that consists of several columns which is what assume you mean. Concatenating them to one column is in general a bad idea, it would for example make it impossible to create foreign key for one or more of these columns. If you google for First Normal Form (1NF) you will find a lot of information on the subject.

Comment: Why do you need the content of the previous PK columns in the new PK column? Why not just use an identity column as PK? For the previous PK columns I would create a unique key constraint.

Comment: If you need more than one column to make your PK - then leave it like that. "Merging" them into a single "artificial" column just to make your PK a single column seems like a horribly bad idea - I see comma- or semicolon-separated, multiple values in a single column - something that violates even the **first normal form** of database design! Either live with the fact your PK is made up from multiple columns, or if that's unacceptable (FK constraint get more cumbersome), then introduce a single `INT IDENTITY` as a **surrogate key** - **DO NOT** merge columns!

Comment: The entity with Pk multicolumn inherits each column from a different parent entity.
The entity with Pk multicolumn is therefore a Weak Entity.
For example, I want to define the edition of a tournament:
 TournamentEdition is an entity.
It inherits the place from  City entity and  year from  Time entity  .
So the Primary Key of TournamentEdition  consists of two columns: PkCity and PkYear

Comment: For example, "Wimbledon" and "2013" may be two values of the columns that make up the primary key.
I'd rather have a Pk with one single column with value "Wimbledon – 2013” than  a Pk with 2 columns with individual values.
In this way I keep the primary key values of parenting classes (Wimbledon from City and 2013 from Year) into the new 1 column PK. This makes Pk with 1 column more understandable than the single column Pk  created  using a counter and put a unique index on two columns.

Comment: @GiovanniTirelli It's already been explained in great detail why this is a terrible idea. I can add one more to it: you will find that concatenating fields makes things far less understandable, not more. Anyone who is reasonably proficient with RDBMS structures will instantly recognise a composite PK or a surrogate key. You can add documentation to each field as well. Whereas a magically concatenated string column will only confuse and frustrate. "Okay, it's dash separated, but is it -, – or —?"

Comment: I think I will use a multicolumn Pk. Thanks very much to all.

Comment: Please allow me one more question gentle guru.
If I create a view based on the table with a multi-column primary key, and then I do the melting of the columns in this view is it a good practice?